# When is initializing a variable reference to the result of a function call useful?

Tags: c++, reference

When is initializing a variable reference to the result of a function call useful? I saw something like that in a codebase. For example:

```
MyType& x = FunctionCall();
```

Would this just prevent the MyType object from being copied and would instead just initialize x to refer to what FunctionCall returns? If that's what happens, what's the difference between that and moving? Wouldn't the compiler know to use the move constructor to move the return value out of the function? What benefit does it have over `MyType x = FunctionCall();`?

Comment: This is only legal if the function returns an lvalue reference. It makes `x` refer to the same object the returned reference referred to. If you used `MyType x;`, `x` would instead be a copy of that object.

Answer (score 3):

> Would this just prevent the MyType object from being copied and would instead just initialize x to refer to what FunctionCall returns?

Yes.

> If that's what happens, what's the difference between that and moving?

In your example `x` doesn't own the object so the object will not get destroyed when `x` goes out of scope.

> Wouldn't the compiler know to use the move constructor to move the return value out of the function?

It will know if it can elide the copy completely (not even a move will be required).

> What benefit does it have over MyType x = FunctionCall();?

It depends on what you want to do with `x`.

In here you return a reference to a `MyType`

```
class Foo {
    MyType& FunctionCall() {
        return data;
    }
    MyType data;
};

MyType x = FunctionCall(); // copies data
MyType& y = FunctionCall(); // holds a reference to data
```

- Any changes you make to `x` above will not affect `data`.
- Any changes you make to `y` will actually be made to `data`.

Here a `MyType` is returned by value:

```
class Foo {
    MyType FunctionCall() {
        MyType data;
        //...
        return data; // return by value, copying is elided
    }
};

MyType x = FunctionCall();    // there is only one instance of MyType
//MyType& y = FunctionCall(); // invalid
```